# Are there any alternatives to adjustsFontSizeToFit for Android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-layout, font-size

I am using flex in Text field to display my values/range. For IOS I am using the properties adjustsFontSizeToFit and minimumFontScale props for Text to achieve the ideal font size and scaling. I want the same scaling to be enabled for Android. Does anyone use any tricks for Android?

```
<View style={{flex: 40}}>
  {
   (Platform.OS === 'ios') ?
    <Text style={{flex: 1, paddingRight: 2}} adjustsFontSizeToFit 
    minimumFontScale={0.5}>
     //if decimal value exists show range
     (pointFivePart_1 === '5') ? 
        <Text style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} >
          <Text style={styles.mainValueStyle}>{first_1}</Text>
          <Text style=styles.decimalValueStyle}> .pointFivePart_1}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.mainValueStyle}>&deg;</Text>
         </Text>
         : <Text style={styles.mainValueStyle} >{min}&deg;</Text>
        }
        //if two values then show the second value as range
{// render largest value if different than min
            (maxSet === minSet) ? null : (
                (pointFivePart_2 === '5') ?
                <Text style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} >
                    <Text style={styles.mainValueStyle}> - {first_2}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.decimalValueStyle}>.{pointFivePart_2}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.mainValueStyle}>&deg;</Text>
                    </Text>
                :
                    <Text style={styles.mainValueStyle} > - {maxSet}&deg;</Text>
                    )
                }
                </Text>
                :
                //same styling for android
```

Comment: Is this still not fixed? This seems like a serious problem, basically makes RN a no-go for Android.

Answer (score 31):

Simple but somehow working solution (crossplatform):

```
fontSize = Math.sqrt(textWidth*textHeight/text.length)
```

where textWidth, textHeight - size of your Text component, text.length - length of your text.

minimumFontScale can be achieved with

```
fontSize = Math.max(fontSize,minimumFontSize)
```

I came to this formula by solving such system of equations:

```
lettersInLine = textWidth/fontSize
lines = textLength/lettersInLine
lines*fontSize = textHeight
```

assuming here that font has square sized (width equal to height) letters.

Though this formula makes sense even without equations. You just

1. calculate square of whole text element
2. calculate square for each letter (dividing whole square to letters number)
3. take square root from letter square to get font size

Comment: How do we find the `textWidth` and `textHeight`?

Comment: you are supposed to know textWidth and textHeight as these are sizes of box that you resize text for

Comment: If you're using Flexbox, you won't know the width or height.

Answer (score 9):

Simply set adjustFontSizeToFit and numberOfLines
**DONT SET fontSize**

```
<Text adjustsFontSizeToFit numberOfLines={1}>This text will fit the width of the container</Text>
```

Comment: All that omitting "fontSize" does, is to use *inherited* fontSize. In my testing, setting fontSize does not prevent "adjustsFontSizeToFit" from working. However, the initial size chosen does seem to effect the adjustment algorithm slightly. `<Text adjustsFontSizeToFit numberOfLines={1} style={{ fontSize: 80 }}>...`

Answer (score 1):

I am using slightly modified version of @nazar solution. I was not able to make it scale as i needed, text would get cut off, because the dynamic height based on screen device would affect the fontSize too much.

Anyways, here is my solution.

```
var fontSize = width / text.length;
var maxSize = width / 5;
fontSize = Math.min(fontSize, maxSize);
```

Maximum font size is defined by 5 letters. Less letters would make too big fontSize in this case. This value can be of course anything. You can make simple function out of this and call it anywhere you need with width parameter, which is idealy something like screen.width * 0.1, second parameter being length of the text and third parameter for the maxSize. So something like this:

```
export function GetFontSize(width, length, max) {      
    var fontSize = width / length;

    var maxSize = width / max;
    fontSize = Math.min(fontSize, maxSize);

    return fontSize;
}
```

Comment: How are the number of lines determined here?

Comment: I needed solution for one line, so this works for only 1 line of text.

Comment: @CosmicSeizure how does this work with flexbox views?

Answer (score -1):

In android I generally define dimension of **TextView** into dimension file inside **values** and for **font** generally use default font from **fontfamily**

here is an example...

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/shipment_text_view"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/send_two_dp"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:text="@{locationViewModel.sameDayShipmentText}"
   android:textColor="@color/black"
   android:textSize="@dimen/send_fourteen_sp"
   android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
   tools:text="6-8 hour delivery" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have edited my initial question to add the code snippet if you could take a look and advise a technique to achieve the result as ios for android. Thanks again!

Comment: @VrushaliRaut this question is posted by OP for react-native solution, not for android specific solution.

Comment: Even if the question were for NATIVE Android (not React Native running on Android), this would NOT be a solution to the question. The question is about AUTOMATICALLY fitting given text into a text element. What this answer shows is merely how to specify text size in an Android layout. If you know of a way in Native Android to get Android to AUTOFIT TEXT (automatically adjust font size so text shrinks as necessary), that might be of some use - could possibly figure out how to adapt that to react native. But as it stands, this answer is not helpful.