# How to adjust font size to fit view in React Native for Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

How I can make the font size of the text auto change inside a view in react native?

I have text with different lengths, some of which doesn't fit the view so decreased the font size. I have checked the docs and found [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#adjustsfontsizetofit) 
but it's for iOS only and I need it for Android.

And does it work with other components like button and touchableopacity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Responsive Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. The previous question asked about setting font sizes based on screen size. This question is about having the font size for a specific Text component scale to fit its parent view based on the text. Imagine the use case of dynamic text coming from a web service where you want it to fill a box of a certain size but can't anticipate how long the strings will be.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657294/are-there-any-alternatives-to-adjustsfontsizetofit-for-android/49381215

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any alternatives to adjustsFontSizeToFit for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657294/are-there-any-alternatives-to-adjustsfontsizetofit-for-android)

Answer (score 49):

Combine these two props, works on Android and iOS:

```
adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}
numberOfLines={1}
```

adjustsFontSizeToFit ensures the font doesn't exceed container, numberOfLines makes sure the text stays in one line.

numberOfLines without adjustsFontSizeToFit would make an ellipsis,
adjustsFontSizeToFit without numberOfLines would reduce the height of size of the text to fit into the containing view, in the case where the containing view has a fixed height or width.

Comment: Nice find, also added `fontSize` as a base size that RN will try to fit before adjusting the size down

Answer (score 30):

A bit improved Jeffy Lee code worked for me

```js
const AdjustLabel = ({
  fontSize, text, style, numberOfLines
}) => {
  const [currentFont, setCurrentFont] = useState(fontSize);

  return (
    <Text
      numberOfLines={ numberOfLines }
      adjustsFontSizeToFit
      style={ [style, { fontSize: currentFont }] }
      onTextLayout={ (e) => {
        const { lines } = e.nativeEvent;
        if (lines.length > numberOfLines) {
          setCurrentFont(currentFont - 1);
        }
      } }
    >
      { text }
    </Text>
  );
};
```

Comment: adjustsFontSizeToFit perfectly works onandroid

Comment: @miteshkalal not always. Only works for some newer versions. On older, besides not changing the font size, may also freeze the app and won't apply ellipsis if there is a max width.

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach. Consider setting the font size according to screen width as following

```
width: Dimensions.get('window').width
```

So in your style try to make a percentage calculation to make the font size fit the screen

```
style={
  text:{
     fontSize:0.05*width
  }
}
```

this will gonna work for all screens (both Android and IOS)

Comment: Where is `0.05` from ?

Comment: @c4k it is just a ration, set it to fit your screen, and u will get this solution working for all the screens

Comment: This does not decrease the font size automatically for longer texts to fit a certain view width, it just sets all fonts to a certain size depending on your screen width. That is not an anwser to the question.

Comment: Agree with @Jenever - this does not answer the OP's question. It solves a completely different problem.

Comment: This is usefull, but doesn' anwer what OP asked

Comment: Unfortunately this sets the font size independently of the length of the contained text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method.

I used the method onLayout to achieve this.

First, I wrapped my Text view inside a fixed size View, then I implement onLayout for both view, so that I can get the height of the fixed size View and the height of the Text view.

Next, if the Text view's required height is more than the height of our View, we decrease the font size of our Text view until the height can fit into our View.

Herein the test code, I made 2 Views, one in pink and one in yellow background, the font size of Text inside the pink View will be adjust to fit the View and the yellow Text will remain the same font size.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState(20)
  const [viewHeight, setViewHeight] = useState(0)
  const [textHeight, setTextHeight] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (textHeight > viewHeight) {
      setSize(size - 1) // <<< You may adjust value 1 to a smaller value so the text can be shrink more precisely
    }
  }, [textHeight])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={{
          margin: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        }}
        onLayout={(event) => {
          var { x, y, width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
          setViewHeight(height)
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: size,
          }}
          onLayout={(event) => {
            var { x, y, width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
            setTextHeight(height)
          }}
        >
          Gemma is a middle grade novel that follows a curious explorer and her ring-tailed lemur, Milo, 
          as they hunt for the “most greatest treasure in the world”. Solving riddles, battling a bell-wearing 
          jaguar, and traveling the Eight Seas, Gemma’s adventures take her from a young girl to a brave captain, 
          whose only limits are the stars.
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          margin: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 20
          }}
        >
          Gemma is a middle grade novel that follows a curious explorer and her ring-tailed lemur, Milo, 
          as they hunt for the “most greatest treasure in the world”. Solving riddles, battling a bell-wearing 
          jaguar, and traveling the Eight Seas, Gemma’s adventures take her from a young girl to a brave captain, 
          whose only limits are the stars.
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

You may notice the pink Text's font is having a shrinking animation when the font size is decreasing, I suggest that you can initial the Text opacity with 0 and after the font adjustment finish set it to 1 so user wont see the ugly animation.

Answer (score 1):

I faced an even more challenging task recently. The task was to fit multiple words with different lengths (eg: Both Plane and Truck has the same character count, but Truck is longer that Plane when written in the same font size.) in Views (one word for each view) of the same size. I used the React Native Animated library to achieve this.
Input words -> Plane, Truck, Bus, Car, Cab

1. Rendered all the given words using the Text component with a fixed, preferably larger font size that exceeds the required width for the longest word.
2. Found the length of the longest word using onLayout function of Text Component.
3. Calculated the scale factor (would be less than 1 due to the assumption in step 1.) along the X-axis needed to fit the longest word within the View.
4. Then rendered each word inside an Animated.Text component wrapped with an Animated.View component which has the fixed length calculated in Step 2.
5. Transformed the ScaleX property of all animated components above from 1 down to scale factor.
6. Transformed the ScaleY property of all Animated.Text components from 1 to scale factor. (duration of all animations are set to 0 milliseconds)
7. Use react state management and/or CSS styles to hide all Text components, which were positioned absolutely.

I implemented the above idea since continuously decreasing font size until the word fits the View using onLayout was visible in the screen to the user, no matter which trick I used to hide it during the running time of the algorithm. Here is a basic implementation, that I have used to develop more robust codes.

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {Animated, View} from 'react-native';

const ScaleText = props => {
  const {word, wordLength, fontWeight} = props;
  const [calculatedLength, setCalculatedLength] = useState(0);
  const [animationEnded, setAnimationEnded] = useState(false);
  const scaleViewAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const scalingAnimation = useCallback(() => {
    Animated.timing(scaleViewAnimation, {
      toValue: wordLength / calculatedLength,
      duration: 0,
    }).start(() => {
      setAnimationEnded(true);
    });
  }, [calculatedLength, scaleViewAnimation, wordLength]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (calculatedLength && !animationEnded) {
      scalingAnimation();
    }
  }, [animationEnded, calculatedLength, scaleViewAnimation, scalingAnimation]);

  return (
    <View style={{width: wordLength, justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
      <Animated.Text
        onLayout={event => {
          let {width} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
          setCalculatedLength(width);
        }}
        numberOfLines={1}
        adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}
        style={[
          {...props},
          {
            fontWeight: fontWeight || 'normal',
            fontSize: Math.floor((30 * 4 * wordLength) / (110 * word.length)),
            transform: [{scaleX: scaleViewAnimation}],
            textAlign: 'center',
            position: 'absolute',
          },
        ]}>
        {word}
      </Animated.Text>
    </View>
  );
};



export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      {['Chamoda', 'Me', 'Nanayakkara'].map((e, i) => (
        <View style={{flex: 1, aspectRatio: 1}} key={i}>
          <ScaleText fontWeight={'bold'} word={e} wordLength={80} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Text component's `adjustsFontSizeToFit` prop has been supported for Android since React Native 0.62. Check the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.62/text#adjustsfontsizetofit).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the number of text resizing the views (user inputs string into an input field currently limited to 30 characters) in my React Native app.  I noticed there are a few properties already implemented for iOS: `adjustsFontSizeToFit minimumFontScale={.4}` however the Android does not have such methods available at this time.

**Note**: Solution which works for me but might not be the "best" possible!

Currently, I'm using a nested ternary operator:

```
fontSize: this.props.driverName.length > 12 && 
this.props.driverName.length < 20 ? heightPercentageToDP('2%') : 
this.props.driverName.length > 20 && this.props.driverName.length < 40 
? heightPercentageToDP('1.75%') : heightPercentageToDP('2.25%')
```

In layman's terms, the above ternary checks the range of characters used and based off the range modifies the fontSize into a '%' inside the view.  The method: `heightPercentageToDP` is a function which I am using to convert the size into a '%' based on the mobile screen's DP (this way it is responsive on a tablet or a mobile phone).

**heightPercentageToDP Code Snippet:**

```
    import { Dimensions, PixelRatio } from "react-native";
    const widthPercentageToDP = widthPercent => {
    const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    // Convert string input to decimal number
    const elemWidth = parseFloat(widthPercent);
    return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel((screenWidth * elemWidth) / 100);
    };
    const heightPercentageToDP = heightPercent => {
    const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
    // Convert string input to decimal number
    const elemHeight = parseFloat(heightPercent);
    return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel((screenHeight * elemHeight) / 100);
    };
    export { widthPercentageToDP, heightPercentageToDP };
```

Credit and source for heightPercentageToDP goes to:
https://medium.com/react-native-training/build-responsive-react-native-views-for-any-device-and-support-orientation-change-1c8beba5bc23.

Answer (score 0):

Without and headache you can use a small library which can maintain the font scale for each device.

```
npm i --save react-native-responsive-fontsize

### import RF from "react-native-responsive-fontsize"

### fontSize: RF(2)
```

But don't forget to add allowFontScaling={false}  props to text. Because ios has auto fon scaling ability so font size could be different from your expectations sometimes.

Comment: This does not seem to shrink text to fit a <View> element.

Answer (score -1):

Quick answer use Text property adjustsFontSizeToFit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).